# Get point with highest and lowest x and y value in python

Tags: python, arrays, max, min

This seems simple, but I would like to do this as efficiently as possible.

Effectively, I am interested in the points that are highest, lowest, most right, and most left.

Given an Array like `[[10,2],[0,2],[1,10],[1,0],[2,3],[5,2],[7,2],[7,3],[3,8],[6,1]]`

I have done this

```
max_x = max([p[0] for p in pts])
min_x = min([p[0] for p in pts])
max_y = max([p[1] for p in pts])
min_y = min([p[1] for p in pts])
```

But I don't just need the `max_x` value though. I need the entire point, and I would rather not iterate though the list more than needed (for the sake of speed with large input).

Bonus points if it's general for N-dimensional points (highest and lowest in each dimension).

Comment: You can always scan through the list to find the point where x == max_x, but it might be just as easy to sort the list based on the first element, pull [0] and [-1], then sort the list based on the second element, and pull [0] and [-1].  It's easy to provide a `key` function to `sort` to use an arbitrary element.

Comment: if you are concerned about performance, use `numpy`.  It can give you orders of magnitude performance improvement over python lists and is designed for multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy was designed for this kind of problem.  It is a performant implementation of multi-dimensional numerical arrays (nested lists of regular shape):

```
import numpy as np

pts = [[10,2],[0,2],[1,10],[1,0],[2,3],[5,2],[7,2],[7,3],[3,8],[6,1]]
arr = np.array(pts)
max_idx = np.argmax(arr, axis=0)
min_idx = np.argmin(arr, axis=0)
max_x, max_y = arr[max_idx]
min_x, min_y = arr[min_idx]
```

output:

```
# max_x, max_y, min_x, min_y
array([10,  2])
array([ 1, 10])
array([0, 2])
array([1, 0])
```

Performance comparison of lists vs arrays for large N

```
from random import random
N = int(1e7) # 10m points

def list_version(N):
    pts = [[random(), random()] for j in range(N)]
    max_x = max(pts, key = lambda x: x[0])
    max_y = max(pts, key = lambda x: x[1])
    min_x = min(pts, key = lambda x: x[0])
    min_y = min(pts, key = lambda x: x[1])
    return max_x, min_x, max_y, min_y

def arr_version(N):
    arr = np.random.random(size=(N,2))
    max_idx = np.argmax(arr, axis=0)
    min_idx = np.argmin(arr, axis=0)
    max_x, max_y = arr[max_idx]
    min_x, min_y = arr[min_idx]
    return max_x, min_x, max_y, min_y

%timeit list_version(N)
4.62 s ± 25.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit arr_version(N)
269 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Awesome! I read that numpy had the best implementation (compared to pythons) but was  not sure how to get it to return what I needed, but it is clear now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `key` argument so you can return the whole point while comparing just one item.

```
from operator import itemgetter

max_x = max(p, key=itemgetter(0))
min_x = min(p, key=itemgetter(0))

max_y = max(p, key=itemgetter(1))
min_y = min(p, key=itemgetter(1))
```

You could also do this with a single loop, instead of calling `min()` and `max()`.

```
min_x = max_x = min_y = max_y = p[0]

for point in p[1:]:
    if point[0] < min_x[0]:
        min_x = point
    if point[0] > max_x[0]:
        max_x = point
    if point[1] < min_y[1]:
        min_y = point
    if point[1] > max_y[1]:
        max_y = point
```

Answer (score 1):

`max` and `min` take a `key` argument where you can specify which value to be used for comparison.

Use:

```
max_x = max(pts, key = lambda x: x[0])
min_x = min(pts, key = lambda x: x[0])
max_y = max(pts, key = lambda x: x[1])
min_y = min(pts, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Output:

```
>>> print(max_x, min_x, max_y, min_y)
[10, 2] [0, 2] [1, 10] [1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[10,2],[0,2],[1,10],[1,0],[2,3],[5,2],[7,2],[7,3],[3,8],[6,1]]

print (list(zip(*[(min(c), max(c)) for c in zip(*l)])))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 0), (10, 10)] # [(minx,miny),(maxx,maxy)]
```

Or just:

```
print ([(min(c), max(c)) for c in zip(*l)])
```

Output:

```
[(3, 10), (2, 9)] # [(minx,maxx),(miny,maxy)]
```

Comment: I think he wants 4 results, not just 2.